Categorical idea of $\mathbb{R}[X]$-Modules
I am a graduate student: I know the basics of Category Theory, Homological Algebra and Representation Theory, but nothing too deep.
I have spent quite some time studying modules over the ring of real polynomials in one indeterminate.
Some of you may already be acquainted with such objects, but I will refresh some of the ideas and make some observations. If you’re already familiar with these considerations, feel free to skip ahead.
Let $V$ be a (left) module over the ring $\mathbb{R}[X]$.
It means that the elements of $V$ can be multiplied on the left by polynomials.
In particular, we can multiply by polynomials of degree zero, namely real scalars.
So if $V$ has a structure of $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module, it necessarily has a structure of real vector space too.
Moreover, consider the action of $X \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ on $V$, hereby denoted with a dot.
\begin{align}
V &\longrightarrow V \\
v &\longmapsto X.v
\end{align}
It is easy to check that this map $V \to V$ is a linear map.
So the action of $X$ uniquely determines a linear endomorphism, call it $f \in \mathrm{End}_\mathbb{R}V$.
In general, to multiply a vector of $V$ by a polynomial is equivalent to letting the same polynomial, evaluated in $f \in \mathrm{End}_\mathbb{R}V$, act on the vector.
For instance
$$ (2X^3 - 2X + 1).v = (2f^3 - 2f + \mathrm{Id})(v)$$
Viceversa, let us start with an ordered pair $(V, f)$, where $V$ is a vector space and $f$ is any element of $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{R}V$.
This uniquely determines a structure of left $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module on $V$.
It is enough to define the action of a polynomial just like in the equation above.
I have realized that one can also go further.
With a little abuse, given $(V, f)$ and $(W, g),$ two left $\mathbb{R}[X]$-modules, a morphism of modules is precisely a linear function $T \colon V \to W$, such that the following diagram commutes.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V @>{f}>> V\\
@VVTV @VVTV\\
W @>{g}>> W
\end{CD}
I have shown that the category $\mathbb{R}[X]-\mathrm{Mod}$ is equivalent to the category $\mathcal{C}$, whose objects are pairs of the form $(V, f)$, where $V$ is an object of the category $\mathrm{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ and $f \in \mathrm{End}_\mathbb{R}V$.
The arrows of $\mathcal{C}$ are the arrows of $\mathrm{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ with the additional property that they satisfy the diagram above.
My question is: there is a name for categories such as $\mathcal{C}$? Is this even a thing in category theory or is it just a fun piece of trivia?
My knowledge of categorical jargon is very limited.
I am very tempted to call $\mathcal{C}$ a product category, since its objects are pairs, but I know that this is incorrect: in fact, the domain of the second entry depends on the first, so $\mathcal{C}$ cannot actually be written as a sort of Cartesian product.
I might be saying a ton of horsepoop right now, but is this maybe a topos? Or anything similar? Maybe Fibred Categories?
The behaviour of $\mathcal{C}$ is reminiscent of sheaves or fibred manifolds to me.
In fact, when we fix the first entry of the ordered pair (the vectorspace) and we let the other entry vary freely, we get a subcategory; these subcategories are indexed by $\mathrm{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$.
Over each one of these categories we have a ring, or a real algebra, namely that of endomorphisms.
It’s as if each of these subcategories had an algebra towering above.
Is this meaningful in any way?
I really have no idea of what I am working with, but I would be very excited to find its place in the bigger picture, possibly even generalizations!
Please excuse my newbiness in category theory.

This category of endomorphisms is an example of a functor category. Namely, there is a category one might call the "free endomorphism," which has a single object $\bullet$ and morphisms freely generated by an endomorphism $f : \bullet \to \bullet$. We can identify $\text{End}(\bullet)$ with the free monoid on one generator (namely $f$), which is $\mathbb{N}$. I will denote this category $B \mathbb{N}$ for reasons which we don't need to get into right now.
Then your category is the category of functors $B \mathbb{N} \to \text{Vect}$.
Many variations of this construction are possible. $\mathbb{N}$ can be replaced with an arbitrary monoid $M$, leading to the category of linear representations of $M$. So in particular we can understand the category of linear representations of a (discrete) group in this language. We can also use the free category on a directed graph; this leads to what are called quiver representations. But the real power of this idea is in using even more general diagram categories than this; for example using the (opposite of) the simplex category produces the category of simplicial vector spaces, and this is studied in homological algebra. And of course $\text{Vect}$ can be replaced by a much more general target category as well.
To give some examples, this language makes it possible to discuss categories such as the following (I will only name the objects):

Two vector spaces $V, W$ and a linear map $f : V \to W$. We can define the kernel and cokernel as functors from this category to $\text{Vect}$.
A vector space $V$ and a linear map $f : V \to V$ satisfying $f^2 = f$ (an idempotent). Non-obviously, this category is equivalent to the category of pairs $(V, W)$ of vector spaces, with the equivalence given by sending $(V, f)$ to $(\text{im}(f), \text{ker}(f))$.
A vector space $V$ and a linear map $f : V \to V$ satisfying $f^n = 1$. This is the category of representations of the finite cyclic group $C_n$.
Two vector spaces $V, W$ and a pair of parallel maps $f, g : V \to W$. This category is used to define equalizers and coequalizers.
Three vector spaces $U, V, W$ and two linear maps $f : U \to V, g : V \to W$ such that $g \circ f = 0$. These are three-term chain complexes. (Actually to include this example we need to generalize the definition a bit to include diagram categories which are enriched over $\text{Ab}$, and using enriched functors.)

If the diagram category $J$ has finitely many objects, it is possible to show that the functor category $[J, \text{Vect}]$ of functors $J \to \text{Vect}$ is equivalent to the category of modules over an algebra constructed out of $J$ called its category algebra. This construction generalizes group algebras, monoid algebras, quiver algebras, and (some) incidence algebras. For $J = B \mathbb{N}$ we get the monoid algebra of $\mathbb{N}$ which is just $K[x]$ (where $K$ is the underlying field).
